# Gradle Eclipse projects in version control tools

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, gradle, version-control

I have created a Gradle project by following the steps described in https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/.

Then, I executed `gradle eclipse` and imported the project to Eclipse using Spring's Gradle IDE Plugin.

Now, the project contains many files and directories, like:

```
src
.gradle
.settings
build
gradle
.classpath
.project
build.gradle
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

Now, using a version control tool, I want to share this project with colleagues that possibly use other tools than Eclipse.
Obviously, some of the files mentioned above (e.g. .classpath, .project) are Eclipse-specific and therefore should not be checked in.

Is there a Gradle documentation explaining which files need to be ignored (e.g. by adding them to svn:ignore when using Subversion)?

And is there a way to have Eclipse do that automatically (just as the bin folder is also ignored by default)?